# What apps to remove from startup to make ubuntu boot faster?

Tags: boot

I have two BIG problems with my laptop, that one of them I want to ask here and it is about boot time latency. my laptop boots really slowly. **Witch app is necessary to remain and witch one can be removed from startup using BUM?**

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is off topic and should be asked somewhere like here http://forums.linuxmint.com/

Comment: That argument has been used before. The fact remains that some modifications are made.

Comment: The only thing where you can -see- a faster boot: change the disc to an SSD

Comment: OK! I Edited my question

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the startup apps are now hidden.

Open a terminal and type:

`sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop`

Open startup applications:

**NOTE:** Don't uncheck/disable what you don't know.

Comment: Are you sure? I think will make them be not hidden just from `startup applications menu`, am I right?

Comment: Yes. All apps are now listed.

Comment: But ok, witch ones should I remove?

Comment: That depends on Your specific needs. I personally found out that disableing the startup apps didn't speed up my boot time.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing the bootchart questions:

- `kthread` and similar stuff is not KDE but kernel related and unavoidable.
- `ureadahead` is supposed to speed up application start on the cost of a longer boot time.
- `upstart-udev-br` bridges udev events into upstart and is required for hot plugging.
- `upstart-socket`, `dbus` and `polkit` are desktop comfort and security related.
- `modem-manager` to `dhclient` depend on network speed.

General recommendations:

- Don't mount NTFS volumes during startup; add `noauto` to partitions that you use rarely.
- If you don't use WLAN or bluetooth, activate the killswitch or disable it by network-manager.
- Remove unused printer drivers; If you rarely ever print, disable the cups service.
- Gnome / Unity can be somewhat hefty on older laptops. Explore alternative desktops like xfce or lxde.
- Consider buying an SSD. That really speeds things up.